# How to confirm on navigating away from page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onbeforeunload

I recently looked up how to do this, and it took *way* too long to find it. So here you guys go, I'm sharing how to make an "`ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO LEAVE THIS PAGE?`" dialog.

Comment: This has already been answered many times. There is no need for another explanation.

Answer (score -1):

It's really quite simple, in the end...

```html
<HTML>

<head>
</head>

<body onbeforeunload="return 'are you sure?';">
  hello...
  <a href="https://www.batalabs.tk">click to test</a>
</body </HTML>
```